# Error while trying to use SFML (some LNK error)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, include, sfml

i've been searching for an answer but all i've found is some similar problem but the answer don't help me at all.

I'm trying to use SFML for a final projet (we would like to create a game like Minigore) and we are trying to load an image and then put it in a sprite.

here's my code:

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML Graphics");

while(App.IsOpened())
{
    sf::Clock Clock;
    while (Clock.GetElapsedTime() < 5.f)
    {
        std::cout << Clock.GetElapsedTime() << std::endl;
        sf::Sleep(0.5f);
    }

    sf::Image image;
    sf::Sprite sprite;

    if(!image.LoadFromFile("BaronsheetBas1.gif"))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        sprite.SetImage(image);
    }
}



    return 0;
}
```

When i compile, i keep having those errors.

```
1>------ Début de la génération : Projet : SFML_Affiche_image, Configuration : Debug Win32 ------
1>La génération a démarré 2013-04-30 19:07:23.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Mise à jour de l'horodatage "Debug\SFML_Affiche_image.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  Toutes les sorties sont à jour.
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: conflit entre la bibliothèque par défaut 'MSVCRT' et les autres bibliothèques ; utilisez /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.obj) : warning LNK4049: symbole défini localement ??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)) importé
1>sfml-window-s.lib(Window.obj) : warning LNK4049: symbole défini localement ??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)) importé
1>sfml-window-s.lib(VideoMode.obj) : warning LNK4049: symbole défini localement ??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)) importé
1>sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImpl.obj) : warning LNK4049: symbole défini localement ??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)) importé
1>sfml-window-s.lib(VideoModeSupport.obj) : warning LNK4049: symbole défini localement ??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)) importé
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(RenderWindow.obj) : warning LNK4217: symbole défini localement ??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)) importé dans la fonction "public: virtual __thiscall std::logic_error::~logic_error(void)" (??1logic_error@std@@UAE@XZ)
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(Image.obj) : warning LNK4217: symbole défini localement ??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)) importé dans la fonction __ehhandler$??0logic_error@std@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@1@@Z
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(Sprite.obj) : warning LNK4049: symbole défini localement ??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)) importé
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(ImageLoader.obj) : warning LNK4217: symbole défini localement ??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)) importé dans la fonction "public: __thiscall std::logic_error::logic_error(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0logic_error@std@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@1@@Z)
1>sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.obj) : warning LNK4049: symbole défini localement ??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)) importé
1>sfml-window-s.lib(Window.obj) : warning LNK4049: symbole défini localement ??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)) importé
1>sfml-window-s.lib(VideoMode.obj) : warning LNK4049: symbole défini localement ??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)) importé
1>sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImpl.obj) : warning LNK4049: symbole défini localement ??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)) importé
1>sfml-window-s.lib(VideoModeSupport.obj) : warning LNK4049: symbole défini localement ??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)) importé
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(RenderWindow.obj) : warning LNK4217: symbole défini localement ??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)) importé dans la fonction "protected: static void __cdecl std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_Xlen(void)" (?_Xlen@?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@KAXXZ)
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(Image.obj) : warning LNK4049: symbole défini localement ??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)) importé
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(Sprite.obj) : warning LNK4049: symbole défini localement ??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)) importé
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(ImageLoader.obj) : warning LNK4217: symbole défini localement ??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)) importé dans la fonction "public: __thiscall std::logic_error::logic_error(class std::logic_error const &)" (??0logic_error@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(ImageLoader.obj) : warning LNK4217: symbole défini localement ?npos@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@2IB (public: static unsigned int const std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::npos) importé dans la fonction "public: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::SaveImageToFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::vector<class sf::Color,class std::allocator<class sf::Color> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?SaveImageToFile@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@VColor@sf@@V?$allocator@VColor@sf@@@std@@@5@II@Z)
1>sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>sfml-window-s.lib(Window.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>sfml-window-s.lib(VideoMode.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImpl.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>sfml-window-s.lib(VideoModeSupport.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(RenderWindow.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: __thiscall std::logic_error::logic_error(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0logic_error@std@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@1@@Z)
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(Image.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(Sprite.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(ImageLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(Image.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,int)" (__imp_?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHPBDH@Z) référencé dans la fonction "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(ImageLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,int)" (__imp_?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHPBDH@Z)
1>sfml-window-s.lib(Window.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,int)" (__imp_?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHPBDH@Z)
1>sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,int)" (__imp_?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHPBDH@Z)
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(ImageLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??$?6DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::LoadImageFromFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::vector<class sf::Color,class std::allocator<class sf::Color> > &,unsigned int &,unsigned int &)" (?LoadImageFromFile@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAV?$vector@VColor@sf@@V?$allocator@VColor@sf@@@std@@@5@AAI2@Z)
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(ImageLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator==<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,char const *)" (__imp_??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@PBD@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::SaveImageToFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::vector<class sf::Color,class std::allocator<class sf::Color> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?SaveImageToFile@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@VColor@sf@@V?$allocator@VColor@sf@@@std@@@5@II@Z)
1>sfml-graphics-s.lib(ImageLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::substr(unsigned int,unsigned int)const " (__imp_?substr@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBE?AV12@II@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::SaveImageToFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::vector<class sf::Color,class std::allocator<class sf::Color> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?SaveImageToFile@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@VColor@sf@@V?$allocator@VColor@sf@@@std@@@5@II@Z)
```

The clock works perfectly (i have tried it alone) but when i tried to load an image then put it into a sprite, those errors appeared.

I have tried to include those librairies to my project, but errors are still there
- sfml-main.lib
- sfml-system-s.lib and sfml-system-s-d.lib
- sfml-graphics-s.lib and sfml-graphics-s-d.lib
- sfml-window-s.lib and sfml-window-s-d.lib

I don't really know whta to do now :/

If any of you guys have an answer or can help me find it, it would be so nice to share it :)

Thanks !!!

Note: sorry for my english, it's not my forst language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are linking to the static libraries of sfml (sfml-system-s.lib etc. ), make sure that the SFML_STATIC variable is set in the preprocessing definitions.

In visual studio you can do it in the preprocessing settings ("preprocessor definitions") as shown here: http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-vc.php

You definitely should link to the static libs on windows if you want to create a game which runs on other machines which do not have sfml dlls installed.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure to understand how to do that. How do I define a SFML_STATIC macro?
Putting the dll I need is not enough ?

Comment: Just put in SFML_STATIC to the preprocessor definitions as shown here: http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/images/start-vc-static.png.
Then always link to static (sfml-*-s.lib) libraries

Comment: When i do that, i go back to the beginning with 17 errors again :/ i really hate sfml ... btw i use 1.6

Comment: Oh well I have been using SFML 2 on several different OS and with different IDEs (also Visual Studio). It works really very good. I recommend that you update to the new version. It is worth the effort.

Comment: I'm starting to think that I will need to do it, because I'm gettin out of time :/ I'll try it and let you know if it works !!!

Comment: There is something i must do wrong cause now i have 105 errors when i use sfml-system-s.lib or any others ....

Comment: OMG omg it works !!!! I had to put the hard path in vc++ for my libs and lib but it works, it didn't like my relative path i guess. I'll try to fix it but for now i manage to draw an image on my screen without any buffer overrun. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Found it guys,

i had to put into Linker Input the librairies

```
sfml-graphics.lib, sfml-window.lib, sfml-system.lib
```

WITHOUT putting -s ....

One last question for you guys, is it normal that i had to put all three .dll in my project, because visual studio was saying it could not find the files ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Yes you have to put in all 3 of them since in sfml these libraries are kept separate (to spare memory if the components are not needed). If you use audio include sfml-audio.lib too

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong slash in your include statement

This

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
```

Should be:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

Comment: you are right, but none of the compiler error are gone because of it :/  Thanks for lettin me know though